# LaTeX video:media embedded by media9

Tags: media9, video

I tried to add a video to my pdf with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}



\title{Relazione moto uniformemente accelerato}
\author{Flavio Cruciani\\
Michelangelo Fancelli\\
Lorenzo Mariotti\\
Matteo Sanna\\
Alessandro Testa}
\date{Verificare il valore dell'accelerazione gravitazionale nel moto uniformemente accelerato conoscendo spazio e tempo, presi empiricamente}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Materiale utilizzato}
1)Metro da 10 metri\\
2)Videocamera (o cellulare)\\
3)Palla\\
4)Oggetti comuni (gomme,matite,...)\\
5)2 sedie\\
6)Cronometro\\
7)Cyberlink Power Directory\\
8)Desmos
\section{Procedimento}
Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare il metro (si veda l'immagine). In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle misurazioni accurate. A questo punto segnare le relative altezze sul muro. Ora, si procede con il calcolo del tempo. Munirsi di un cronometro, prendere l'oggetto, posizionarlo in prossimità dell'altezza presa in considerazione, lasciarlo cadere, e calcolare quanto tempo impiega a toccare la sedia. Ripetere l'operazione molte volte, soprattutto se le altezze sono piuttosto basse, per ridurre il numero degli errori. Ripetere il tutto per ogni altezza a portata d'uomo (considerando anche la sedia, non più di 2 metri). Per tutte quelle distanze relativamente elevate, usufruire di balconi o terrazze, considerando ovviamente la portata del metro. A questo punto, fissare il metro e farlo scendere fino a toccare il suolo. Controllare che la misurazione dell'altezza sia precisa, pertanto ci si dovrà recare al luogo presso cui cadrà l'estremità del metro e regolarlo. Successivamente far cadere gli oggetti presi in considerazione e segnare i tempi (se ne consigliano molti, in modo che verranno recuperati tutti insieme evitando così perdite di tempo, ed inoltre oggetti che facciano piuttosto rumore, in modo tale da capire, oltre che vedendo, quando l'oggetto avrà toccato terra). Successivamente, calcolare il valore dell'accelerazione gravitazionale usufruendo dei dati ottenuti utilizzando la formula 
\begin{equation*}
g = \frac{2s}{t^2}
\end{equation*}
la quale deriva dalla legge oraria del moto uniformemente accelerato
\begin{equation*}
    s = \frac{1}{2}\times g\times t^2
\end{equation*}
A questo punto, realizzare i grafici che mettono a confronto la legge oraria con il vero valore di $g$ con quello da noi ottenuto utilizzando un qualsiasi disegnatore di grafici online come Desmos.
Fatto ciò, è il momento di registrare il moto della caduta (si consigliano elevate altezze per la registrazione in modo da avere un risultato migliore). Quindi, posizionare ila videocamera o il cellulare in modo tale che rimanga fermo e che riprenda correttamente tutto il moto del corpo (ovviamente esso dovrà riprendere il moto da terra). Quindi, lanciare la palla (o anche altre per poi scegliere il risultato migliore). Infine, montare il video con Cyberlink Power Directory (o un qualsiasi altro buon montatore di video) in modo tale che si possano vedere le variazioni di spazio, tempo e velocità mano a mano che il corpo si sposta.


\includemedia[ 
width=1\linewidth,height=1\linewidth, 
activate=pageopen, 
flashvars={ 
modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar 
&autohide=1 % controlbar autohide 
&showinfo=1 % no title and other info before start 
&rel=1 % no related videos after end 
} 
]{}{GravitaOFFICIALCLIPCHAMP1080p.mp4}


\section{Misurazioni e calcoli}
$h\textsubscript{1} = 0.5m$\\
$t\textsubscript{1}$ = $0.14s$|$020s$|$0.13s$|$0.14s$|$0.20s$| $0.20s$|$0.14s$|$0.13s$|$0.20s$|$0.20s$\\
$t\textsubscript{m1} = 0.168s$\\
$h\textsubscript{2} = 1m$\\
$t\textsubscript{2}$ = $0.27s$|$0.28s$|$0.26s$|$0.27s$|$0.33s$| $0.20s$|$0.34s$|$0.34s$|$0.33s$|$0.27s$\\
$t\textsubscript{m2} = 0.289s$\\
$h\textsubscript{3} = 1.5m$\\
$t\textsubscript{3}$ = $0.41s$|$0.40s$|$0.40s$|$0.34s$|$0.26s$| $0.40s$|$0.33s$|$0.40s$|$0.41s$|$0.40s$\\
$t\textsubscript{m3} = 0.375s$\\
$h\textsubscript{4} = 2m$\\
$t\textsubscript{4}$ = $0.48s$|$0.46s$|$0.46s$|$0.46s$|$0.53s$| $0.53s$|$0.47s$|$0.53s$|$0.54s$|$0.53s$\\
$t\textsubscript{m4} = 0.499s$\\
$h\textsubscript{5} = 4.8m$\\
$t\textsubscript{5}$ = $0.99s$|$0.99s$|$0.99s$|$0.93s$|$0.86s$| $0.92s$|$0.99s$|$1.05s$|$0.86s$|$0.86s$\\
$t\textsubscript{m5} = 0.944s$\\
$g\textsubscript{1} = 35.4308m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{2} = 23.9461m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{3} = 21.\overline{3}m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{4} = 16.0642m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{5} = 10.7728m/s^2$\\
\section{Realizzazione del video}
Il video del moto uniformemente accelerato mostra come variano i valori spazio, tempo e velocità mano a mano che la palla blu si sposta verso il basso a causa della forza di attrazione gravitazionale. Dopo che il fenomeno è stato ripreso dal cellulare, è stato fortemente rallentato per permettere di cogliere pienamente il moto dell’oggetto e per poter individuare i valori in corrispondenza della posizione della palla. Nel video quest’ultima si vede spostata rispetto alla posizione precedente per un totale di 17 volte. A questo punto, per calcolare il tempo reale per ogni posizione della palla, è stato necessario confrontare il tempo reale con quello del video. Difatti i 17 fotogrammi dell’oggetto non erano tutti della stessa durata, ma oscillavano tutti tra 0,32s e 0,36s del video. Dunque, ogni volta che l’oggetto cambiava posizione, veniva preso il tempo del video per poi calcolare il tempo reale per quella esatta posizione della palla. Allora, si impostava la seguente proporzione:\\
\begin{equation*}
y:x = 5.72s : 0.944s
\end{equation*}
\begin{center}
y = tempo del video\\
x = tempo reale\\
5,72s è la durata del moto nel video\\
0,944s è la durata del moto nella realtà
\end{center}
A questo punto, una volta che si è conosciuto il tempo per una determinata posizione, si è potuto trovare lo spazio applicando la legge del moto uniformemente accelerato:
\begin{equation*}
s = \frac{1}{2}\times 10.7728m/s^2\times t^2
\end{equation*}
e per calcolare la velocità la seguente formula:
\begin{equation*}
V = 10,7728m/s^2 \times t
\end{equation*}
A questo punto il video è stato nuovamente rallentato per poter visualizzare meglio i valori di spazio, velocità e tempo mano a mano che la palla scendeva.


\section{Conclusioni}
Dai valori dell'accelerazione gravitazionale ottenuti, si può dire che questo esperimento è riuscito in parte, perché quelli con altezze relativamente basse sono molto diversi dalla vera $g$, a differenza dell'ultimo, quello con 4.80m. Gli errori di misurazione delle altezze (questione di mm o pochi cm) sono ininfluenti praticamente. Gli errori che hanno portato ad avere valori assai diversi riguardano invece la misurazione del tempo. Difatti, nei primi 4 esperimenti gli spazi erano troppo piccoli per un occhio umano per avere risultati corretti. Difatti bisogna considerare i tempi di reazione, che sulle distanze ridotte influiscono notevolmente sul risultato finale. Infatti l'esperimento è riuscito solo con una grande altezza (4.80m). Pertanto, si può affermare che esperimenti di questo tipo hanno successo solo con grandi spazi poiché i tempi di reazione influiscono sempre di meno mano a mano che aumenta l'altezza e quindi si ottengono valori sempre più vicini a $g$.
Di seguito viene riportato un grafico che mostra l'andamento dello spazio in funzione del tempo per ciascuna accelerazione gravitazionale calcolata, per meglio rendersi conto di quanto detto precedentemente.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=200mm]{example-image.png}
\caption{I grafici ottenuti con le misurazioni a confronto con quello vero.\$g\textsubscript{rosso} = 9.81m/s^2$\$g\textsubscript{verde} = 10.7728m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{nero} = 16.0642m/s^2$\ $g\textsubscript{viola} = 21.\overline{3}m/s^2$\ 
$g\textsubscript{Blu} = 23.9461m/s^2$\ $g\textsubscript{arancione} = 35.4308m/s^2$\\
 \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}

Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.98  \label{overflow}}

I've run across a } that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, \def\a#1{...} and \a} would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the \par that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your } was spurious, just type 2 and it will go away.
 main.tex, line 98
Runaway argument?
\@captype {\def \reserved@a *{\nobreak \@xcentercr }\reserved@a }\def \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.98  \label{overflow}}

I suspect you've forgotten a }, causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

The system didn't give my errors. I downloaded the pdf and there was a yellow image in which there was written "media embedded by media9" instead of my video. How can I solve this problem?
There are these but there aren't referred to the video

Comment: You could have edited the other question :-(

Comment: but why it doesn't work! It's too urgent

Comment: Cannot believe this compiles without error to a PDF.

Comment: @AlexG: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366489/latex-unknown-graphics-extension-mp4#comment903490_366489 also

Comment: @AlexG  I updated the question

Comment: @David Carlisle I updated the question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok now I'll post all the code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I deleted the first and updated this question

Comment: The posted code produces the error `! Undefined control sequence.
\@author ->Flavio Cruciani\Michelangelo`

Comment: oh you have lost every `\\ ` how did you add the code??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle really? And what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh no, I don't know why but I lost // With <pre> <code>

Comment: don't use `<pre>` or `code` just highlight the code and use the `{}` button (or control-k)  (I fixed it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. So, did you find the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57654/discussion-between-curio-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 2):

there are numerous warnings such as

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 57--77
```

due to misuse of `\\` (which should never be used at the end of a paragraph)

but the error is

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.108  \label{overflow}}
```

that error is completely unrelated to the video, you have fragile commands in the caption and some of your `$` intended to start math are `\$` which just typesets `$`

If the caption is marked up as

```
\caption[short caption]{I grafici ottenuti con le misurazioni a confronto con quello vero.
$g\textsubscript{rosso} = 9.81m/s^2$\ $g\textsubscript{verde} = 10.7728m/s^2$\\
$g\textsubscript{nero} = 16.0642m/s^2$\ $g\textsubscript{viola} = 21.\overline{3}m/s^2$\ 
$g\textsubscript{Blu} = 23.9461m/s^2$\ $g\textsubscript{arancione} = 35.4308m/s^2$
 \label{overflow}}
```

then you get no error.

Note that `\textsubscript` is not intended to be used in math it should be, for example `g_{\mathrm{nero}}`

Comment: ok, I fixed this problem, but there wasn't still the video